# Duplicate Timestamps in SQL Server Query: How to add millisecond and avoid duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table [myTable] in SQL Server:

```
ID | Timestamp [datatype= datetime]
1  | 2013-08-05 23:09:02.000
2  | 2013-11-05 23:00:00.000
3  | 2013-08-05 23:09:02.000
4  | 2013-11-05 23:00:00.000
5  | 2014-01-01 22:00:00.000
```

In the table I have [sometimes] some duplicated timestamps. Using a SELECT statement, how can I add 1 millisecond to each of the duplicated values so then I have only unique timestamps?

Output would be:

```
ID | Timestamp
1  | 2013-08-05 23:09:02.000
2  | 2013-11-05 23:00:00.000
3  | 2013-08-05 23:09:02.001
4  | 2013-11-05 23:00:00.001
5  | 2014-01-01 22:00:00.000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of Timestamp?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson edited in question. Thanks for asking.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad practice. Why would your time stamps need to be unique?

Comment: @SpectralGhost Because the system I am using to query this data doesn't allow duplicated timestamps as timestamps are PK for this system. My final query will include the real timestamos as a varchar concatenated with the another values.

Comment: Timestamps are PK?  Oh dear.

Comment: @Dalek the question is not clear. you want to add that millisecond in the output or in the table?

Comment: @Paolo to the SELECT output

Comment: So if you add 1 millisecond, and now the record is duplicated with yet another row, will you continuously add milliseconds until you aren't duplicated? can you see how on a busy system this could become a mess?

Comment: I don't understand how you'd be able to query that system if the PKs have been altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, DATEADD(MILLISECOND,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Timestamp ORDER BY Id)-1,Timestamp) Timestamp
```

Comment: The idea is good but will not work with `datetime` since it does not have a precision of 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(ms,(ID*10),tbl.[TIMESTAMP]),tbl.*
FROM [TABLE] tbl
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [TIMESTAMP],Count(*) [CNT]
    FROM [TABLE]
    GROUP BY [TIMESTAMP]
    HAVING count(*)>1
) dupe ON dupe.[TIMESTAMP]=tbl.[TIMESTAMP]
```

Comment: @Dalek Updated. I read the question as you needed to add to the field so they were unique.

Comment: Did you really mean to add `ID` milliseconds and not `1` or perhaps `CNT`. BTW, you have the same issue as @mordechai here. "datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, "

Comment: Added ID*10 to resolve the rounding issue. I have doubts about this being the end all solution because the desired approach seems flawed.

Answer (score 0):

If the time stamp column is not part of a key and all you want is to avoid duplicates, you can use rowversion instead.

```
CREATE TABLE table (
--,TIMESTAMP rowversion
)
```